# Facebook app working only for administrator. Why?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created a facebook app. From my website the users can log in using their facebook account. Once they log in successfully the facebook javascript API which i use will post the URL to the user's newfeed with their permission.

The problem is, this is working perfectly when i use my account to login from the website and I could see the post in my newsfeed.

When logging in with someone else account the post is not seen in their newsfeed.

Note : I am the only administrator of facebook app and Sandbox mode is disabled.

Is there any settings i need to make such that this functionality works for all the users ?

Code Used :

```
//Get values from hidden field
var appid = document.getElementById("appid").value;
var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
var link = document.getElementById("link").value;
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var picture = document.getElementById("picture").value;
var description = document.getElementById("description").value;
var Post_to_fb = document.getElementById("Post_to_fb").value;


var Authenticated = "";
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
} (document));

//Init the SDK upon load
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: appid, // App ID
        channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/channel', // Path to your Channel File
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML 
    });



    // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
            var uid = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.authResponse.userID + "/picture";
            FB.api('/me', function (me) {
                document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
                document.getElementById('profileImg').src = uid;
            })
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';

            var e = document.getElementById("ctl00_cphRightControls_FaceBookPlugin_ddlSocialSwitch");
            var Social_switch = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

            //Post to FB only if Social switch is ON
            if (Social_switch == "on") {
                //Post to FB only for Main URL and not when clicking the internal links
                if (Post_to_fb == "True") {

                var opts = {
                    message: message,
                    link: link,
                    name: name,
                    picture: picture,
                    description: description 
                };

                FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', opts, function (response) {
                    if (!response || response.error) {
//                        alert('Posting error occured');
                    }
                    else {
//                        alert('Success - Post ID: ' + response.id);
                    }
                }); 
               } 
           } 

        } else {
            // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
        }

    });
    $("#auth-logoutlink").click(function () {
        FB.logout(function () {
            window.location.reload();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you echo plain text response from B.api('/me/feed', 'post', opts, function (response) ? You able to get the post_id if success. Or you compare the result between admin and fake user. I want to make sure you success post or not. If not success, please debug your User access token(not App access token!) at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and make sure you see the "Scope" with "publish_stream" permission.

Comment: @林果皞 I am getting the alert as "Success" when I login (App administrator) But when i login in with another account, alert returns error message. I debugged with the access token and found that "Publish_Stream" is available in scope. What might be the problem then ?

Comment: @林果皞 I think there is no issues in the script i use to post on FB because it is working perfectly when I log in. Is there anything missing in the facebook developer dashboard that i am doing wrong ? Please help.

Comment: Can you replace user access token inside Access Token field at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer, then select "POST" method and insert "/me/feed". Do the same thing using your user access token and also other people's user access token. then compare the result. Also, do http "GET" request to /me/feed for those user access token, to make sure those token is valid for simple GET request.

Comment: Where is your FB.login call? Maybe some missing permissions? If you have done other tests you can have authorized your app with more permissions than the other users. Be sure that when you call the FB.login method you specify: {scope: 'publish_stream'}

Comment: Also, as you mentioned you got the alert for error when you tried posting with another User's account. Could you just also tell the value of `response.error`

Comment: Can you comment out the picture:picture part? Does it work without trying to post a photo? I feel like you may need more permissions like 'photo_upload'

Comment: have you checked the "Privacy Settings" of your test user? Once, I was caught by the user's privacy settings that do not allow any app to access their data

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your cookies between logging out of your administrator account and into your dev account, or even better just test using different browsers ([chrome profiles](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364824) are great for this)

The cookie that the facebook js sdk creates for a user (fbsr_{APP_ID}) sticks around for the first load of the next user login and screws things up a bit for that first page load when using it off-canvas (on a website like you mentioned). Facebook isn't completely streamlined for using multiple accounts in one browser how developers often use them. It's very possible that because of this it's trying to post as the wrong user and causing the error. That's my best guess without having more info.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the "Country restricted" to United Kingdom was the problem. Upon switching it off, to allow all countries, it worked with other accounts. Secondly, the app must be in Live mode to allow public access. In Dev mode, only Admininstrator and Test users can access.

Answer (score 0):

Long solved (I hope), but I experienced the same behaviour and fixed it by requesting Advanced Access to public_profile.  App Review->Permissions and Features

This was not obvious to me, as it seemed to be automatically granting this access according to the interface.

The specific error message non-admin users were getting was "Feature Unavailable: Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app as we are updating additional details for this app.  Please try again later."